# List output convert to a matrix

Tags: r

I am writing the following program for matrices.

X <- replicate(3, rnorm(20))

center_apply <- function(x) {

apply(x, 2, function(y) y - mean(y))

}

centX<-center_apply(X)

ID <- matrix(0, 20, 20)

g1<-replicate(3, rnorm(20))

N  <- 20

n  <- 4

HL<-list()

ZETA<-list()

for (j in seq(1,N,n)) {

mm <- j + n - 1

v <- g1[j:mm, ]

set <- colSums(v)

M <- ID[j:mm, ]

AD<-colSums(M)

PART <- sweep(t(centX), 2, AD, `*`)

SEC <- rowSums(PART) / N

ZET <- set - SEC

ZETA[[j]] <- ZET %*% t(ZET)

if (j==1){

```
HL[j]<-ZETA[1]
```

}else {

```
HL[[j]]<-ZETA[j]- HL[j-n]
```

}

}

HL[1]

HL[5]

This run for `HL[1]` but the rest. I get an error `"non-numeric argument to binary operator"`.
I greatly appreciate your help on this.

Comment: hi, can you try to add a small example of the data inputs to this to allow your code to run please. Even better, if you could describe what you are trying to do (with reference to inputs and outputs). Thanks,

Comment: Thank you@user20650. I edited my post. When you run this, you will see the errors. Thank you very much for helping on this.

Comment: Groan: What's `t(centX)`. Start a session with no variables defined and test your code.

Comment: I am really sorry. I posted the correct one. Thank you again..

Comment: Kan, thanks for the update. To correctly isolate what is wrong in your code can you make sure it runs please. As @42 mentioned can you run it in a fresh R sesion to make sure it works / reproduces the error you see. For example, when I run your code, I get *Error: object 'ZETA' not found* as it has not been initialised prior to the loop. So if I go ahead and do that, I then get a different error from what you get. If you can make sure your code and error is reproducible we will all be trying to correct the same stuffs. Thanks.

Comment: (ps what does this do *apply(m0, c(1,2), function(x) sample(c(0,1),1))* as its not getting assigned ???)

Comment: I apologize my mistakes. I found one error on "apply" function and corrected it. But I don't get error on object "ZETA". I have being working on this about two weeks so I understood this error coming form the loop. I added "ZETA<-list()" above "for (j in seq..)" . If you still get this error, please remove this part and run. Other than that, I have one error "non-numeric argument to binary operator". I would like to upload or send my R-script if it is possible. If you have any question, please let me know. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me as though you are extracting a sublist when you should be using "[[" to extract a numeric value:

```
 else {
       HL[[j]]<-ZETA[[j]]- HL[[j-n]]; cat(str(ZETA)); cat(str(HL))
       }
```

The "[" operator in R always returns a list value if its argument is a list. It's worthwhile to read and re-read the `?Extract` page at least ten times, paying careful attention to every paragraph. This is what I now get (although it looks a bit weird):

```
> str(HL)
List of 17
 $ : num [1:3, 1:3] 0.0631 -0.3173 -0.5259 -0.3173 1.5962 ...
 $ : NULL
 $ : NULL
 $ : NULL
 $ : num [1:3, 1:3] 5.9151 -0.0913 3.6557 -0.0913 -1.5683 ...
 $ : NULL
 $ : NULL
 $ : NULL
 $ : num [1:3, 1:3] -4.31 -1.76 -7.33 -1.76 3.72 ...
 $ : NULL
 $ : NULL
 $ : NULL
 $ : num [1:3, 1:3] 4.61 2.47 7.42 2.47 -2 ...
 $ : NULL
 $ : NULL
 $ : NULL
 $ : num [1:3, 1:3] 0.00182 0.28352 -11.72707 0.28352 3.65242 ...
> HL[[5]]
           [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
[1,]  5.9151241 -0.0912828  3.655714
[2,] -0.0912828 -1.5683258 -2.859833
[3,]  3.6557136 -2.8598327 -2.747340
```

Comment: Just a note on why it looks weird: Indexing an a assignment to an `n`-th item in a list automatically creates NULL entries for any indices needed to "fill the gap" between `n` and the initial length of the list.